# Risks with compiling random GitHub repositories into ASTs?

Tags: github, sandbox, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to be able to pick a GitHub repository at random, clone it and compile it into an abstract syntax tree (AST), and do this repeatedly. Do I need to sandbox the compilation in some way to protect my computer from getting harmed (I will just compile the code into an AST, not run it), and how can I do that in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need sandboxing if there is no execution.

But just in case, the way to do that sandboxing would be through a VM (VirtualBox, VMware) which would share the internet connection of your host, and git clone/run your process within said VM.

Comment: So if I compile a CMake project, the CMake scripts won't be able to write to parts of my computer that I don't want it to write to? Or what kind of execution are you talking about? I guess compilation is also execution, just of the program that performs the compilation instead of the program that is compiled. :P

Comment: @HelloGoodbye Regarding wrting, you usually mount the part of your host disk you want to use (for persistent data) into the VM.